# How to move a view inside another view in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I would like to move a textview inside a container view without deleting or re-creating them. How can I do it using my storyboard ? I just want to move highlighted Text View inside to Container View. Drag & Drop is not working, it is just changing the order of views. [image]

Guidance needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If container view is of container kind. Drag should work I believe. Just drag your `textView` over `containerView` and hold until your container get surrounded by blue line like in image then drop it there. [image]

If you see here I am dragging and dropping `Label 0 - 12` inside a collection view.